# FFMpeg : Overlay an image or gif on top of a video for X seconds while the video remains paused

Tags: ffmpeg

My requirement is as follows:

1. Input video is an MP4
2. Overlay can be either gif or png.

Overlay should appear over the the input video at a timestamp. It should last for 5 seconds. If it's a gif, it should play for that 5 seconds on loop. During this 5 seconds when overlay appears, the background video should be paused ( both audio and video) and then resume once overlay disappears. Overlay can occur anywhere from 0th to the last frame.

Ive tried inserting the image at a timestamp, calculating the frame at that timestamp, then using `loop` but Im running into one or the other issue, either with audio or video. Ive also tried splitting video into two parts at the time of overlay, applying to one then merging them.

Im at this for last 3 days and hoping someone helps with the command, as its beyond me at this point.

Comment: Can you post the code you already tried?

Comment: tpad apad concat `ffmpeg -t 3 -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -ss 3 -i input.mp4 -lavfi "
[0]tpad=stop_duration=5:stop_mode=clone[p];
[p][1]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10:enable='between(t,3,8)'[v];
[0:a]apad=pad_dur=5[a];
[v][a][2:v][2:a]concat=2:1:1
" -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 20 -c:a aac -q:a 4 -y /tmp/out.mp4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uff took me hours to get this right. The comment from @Баяр Гончикжапов and the answer from this topic helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414641/repeat-last-frame-in-video-using-ffmpeg

You have to use the tpad filter on the part before the overlay that way you can pause the last frame of that part for as long as you want. Next you pad the audio of part 1 to compensate for the extra time while the video is paused and showing the overlay with apad filter.

Continuing, you contact the video parts + audio parts and on the resulting video you apply the overlay.

As an example I'm going to use a part 1 of 30 seconds then pause with overlay for 5 seconds and a part 2 with also 30 seconds.

**For a png image:**

```
ffmpeg -reinit_filter 0 -t 30 -i "input.mkv" -ss 30 -t 30 -i "input.mkv" -t 35 -i apple.png -map_metadata -1 -filter_complex "[0]tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[Part1];[0]aselect='between(t,0,30)',apad=pad_dur=5[Audio1];[1]aselect='between(t,0,30)'[Audio2];[Part1][Audio1][1][Audio2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vid];[vid][2]overlay=x=W-w:y=10:enable='between(t,30,35)'[vid]" -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "output_png.mp4"
```

**For a gif image:**

```
ffmpeg -reinit_filter 0 -t 30 -i "input.mkv" -ss 30 -t 30 -i "input.mkv" -t 35 -stream_loop -1 -i horse.gif -map_metadata -1 -filter_complex "[0]tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[Part1];[0]aselect='between(t,0,30)',apad=pad_dur=5[Audio1];[1]aselect='between(t,0,30)'[Audio2];[Part1][Audio1][1][Audio2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vid];[vid][2]overlay=x=W-w:y=10:enable='between(t,30,35)'[vid]" -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "output_gif.mp4"
```

Comment: This is spectacular! Works like a charm. It didnt work as expected for me for gif insert time of 0th second, I worked around it by setting time to 00:00:00:001. I dont think I fully understood the use of `-i "input.mkv" -t 35`, could you explain the purpose ?

Comment: -t 30 -i input.mkv: -t 30 is the length of the video, grab the first 30 seconds from input, time 0-30s | -ss 30 -t 30 -i input.mkv:  ss = skip first 30 seconds and video length 30 so it will grap this times from the second imput: 30-60s